# Why useDispatch runs, but the state does not change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Used in the project connect, but now I want to switch to hooks

When you enter input, the action is dispatched:
`onChange={(e) => dispatch(actions.setInputText(e.target.value))}`

but when outputting the todo element is an empty string, although when using connect everything worked fine?

```
const inputText = useSelector(state => state.inputText.data)
```

↑ This is a string with input text ↑



My project - [scintillating-plantation.surge.sh](http://scintillating-plantation.surge.sh)

Code:

```js
    import React from "react";
    import actions from "../../../actions";
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
    
    export default function AddTodoInputBtn(props) {
      const inputText = useSelector(state => state.inputText.data);
      const inputActiveClass = useSelector(state => state.inputActiveClass.data);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      const inputNode = React.createRef();
      function changeInputLogo() {
        if (inputActiveClass === "") {
          dispatch(actions.setInputActiveClass("_active"));
          inputNode.current.focus();
          return;
        }
        dispatch(actions.setInputActiveClass(""));
        dispatch(actions.setInputText(""));
      }
    
      return (
        <form
          onSubmit={(e) => {
            window.console.log(inputText);    <----------------here is I show const inputText = useSelector(state => state.inputText.data);
            dispatch(actions.setInputActiveClass(""));
            inputNode.current.blur();
            props.onAddTodo(e);
          }}
          className={`todo_block-add_todo add_todo_block add_todo_block${inputActiveClass}`}
        >
          <div
            className={`add_todo_block-icon${inputActiveClass}`}
            onClick={changeInputLogo}
          />
          <input
            ref={inputNode}
            autoComplete="off"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Add List"
            className="add_todo_block-input"
            id="input"
            value={inputText}
            onChange={(e) => dispatch(actions.setInputText(e.target.value))}
            onClick={changeInputLogo}
          ></input>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className={`add_todo_block-btn add_todo_block-btn${inputActiveClass}`}
          >
            <div>Add</div>
          </button>
        </form>
      );
    }
```

reducer:

```
const first = {
  data: "",
};

const second = {
  data: false,
};

const third = {
  data: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [
    { label: "Wash Kitchen", isComplete: false },
    { label: "Go To Theater", isComplete: false },
  ],
};

const fourth = {
  data: [],
};

const fifth = {
  data: [],
};

const sixth = {
  data: "All",
};

const seventh = {
  data: "",
};

function inputText(state = first, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_INPUT_TEXT_DATA":
      return { ...state, data: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function isShowTips(state = second, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_SHOW_TIPS_DATA":
      return { ...state, data: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function todoList(state = third, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_TODO_LIST_DATA":
      return { ...state, data: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function doneTodos(state = fourth, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_DONE_TODOS_DATA":
      return { ...state, data: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function undoneTodos(state = fifth, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_UNDONE_TODOS_DATA":
      return { ...state, data: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function todosType(state = sixth, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_TODOS_TYPE_DATA":
      return { ...state, data: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function inputActiveClass(state = seventh, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_INPUT_ACTIVE_CLASS_DATA":
      return { ...state, data: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default {
  inputText,
  isShowTips,
  todoList,
  doneTodos,
  undoneTodos,
  todosType,
  inputActiveClass,
};
```

Comment: please add reducer and `setInputText` code to your question

Comment: @HagaiHarari
add

Comment: and `setInputActiveClass` action